# Differentiating between aliased types in C++

Tags: c++

C++ has some nice type trait utilities for determining information about types, including whether two types are the same:

```
using latitude = float;
using longitude = float;
assert((std::is_same_v<int, float> == false));
assert((std::is_same_v<latitude, float> == true));
```

But, is there a way to determine whether a type is *exactly* the same, ignoring aliasing, at compile time? Something like

```
std::is_exact_v<latitude, longitude> // should return false; is_same_v returns true
```

Am I asking for too much of type reflection in C++?

Comment: I believe the static reflection work was going the direction of including this, but it's still got a whole bunch of work left before it's in the language.

Comment: The Boost library has: strong typedef which will allow you to differentiate.

Comment: *aliasing* is **exactly** the same.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't differentiate between them. If you work with classes public inheritance helps, but that can't be done with `float`s.

```
struct Name:std::string{};
struct Adress:std::string{}
```

You can create a wrapper around `float`, and inherit from that but this can leed to performance-loss (copying) and also a ton of work